# Remove \r in between merged csv file with paste command

Tags: linux, command, csv, paste

I merged 3 csv files with command like this.

```
paste -d "," a.csv b.csv c.csv > result.csv
```

The resulting csv has an unexpected line break in between columns of b.csv and c.csv in each line like:

```
col-a1, col-a2, col-b1, col-b2, col-b3
,col-c1, col-c2 ...
```

b.csv was originally tsv and transformed into csv with command like:

```
cut -f3-5 b.tsv | tr "\t" "," > b.csv
```

where the 5th field of original b.tsv was the last field in a line.

Why was \r there?

Given that, I have to use the paste command, how to remove the line break so that all the columns of the 3 csv are in one line?

Update:
In response to the comment below, the output of this command

```
LC_ALL=C sed -n 'l;2q' result.csv
```

was like this:

```
col-a1, col-a2, col-b1, col-b2, col-b3\r,col-c1, col-c2$
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to Stéphane Chazelas for the hint given in the comment.

Finally I got my answer. In order to remove `\r`, the command for transforming tsv to csv should be:

```
cut -f3-5 b.tsv | tr "\t" "," | tr -d "\r" > b.csv
```